# vector triple product does not go from $[\dot{M} \times [H \times M]]+[M \times [H \times \dot{M}]]$ to $2\dot{M}(H,M)$

Tags: vector-analysis, cross-product

I have the following term $ [M \times [H \times M]] $ under the time derivative.
After using the rule of the derivate of the product I get:
$$[\dot{M} \times [H \times M]]+[M \times [\dot{H} \times M]]+[M \times [H \times \dot{M}]]$$
let skip the middle term. Now we have 2 terms,
$$ X = [\dot{M} \times [H \times M]]+[M \times [H \times \dot{M}]]$$
applying bac-cab rule I get:
$$H(\dot{M},M) - M(\dot{M},H) + H(M,\dot{M}) - \dot{M}(M,H)$$
Now I have some problems. As far as I understand there is no need to be precize in which terms should be calculated first (for instance, scalar product of 2 last terms or scalar product of 2 first terms). May I do like this?
$$H(\dot{M},M) - M(\dot{M},H) + H(M,\dot{M}) - (M,H)\dot{M}$$
I should get something looking like $2\dot{M}(H,M)$. Nevertheless I do see only that everything collapse.

Found one more thing. Such a result I need, should be get as $[H \times [\dot{M} \times M]] - X$ .

Comment: The product you have written is not equal to $2\dot{M} (H,M)$ without further properties. Could you give some context to find out why it does?

Comment: dear Rogelio-Molina, thank you, now I have recalculated all the terms before this sum and found one more, I did new  addition at the bottom of the text.

Comment: Thanks for the edition! I am however a little confused as to what $X$ stands for, is it something unkown whose structure we are after? also it goes together with $[H \times [M \times M]]$ which should be zero because $M \times M =0$.

Comment: Dear  Rogelio-Molina, I am so sorry(poor sleep), but I did check everyhting else, must be alright. I can ommit X, but the idea is that I can use only 2 terms of the first 3 term expression. Because the third one looks like in a book. The problem is only in why  $[H\times[\dot{M}\times M]] -[\dot{M}\times[H\times M]] - [M\times[H\times \dot{M}]] \neq 2\dot{M}(H,M)$

Comment: $\dot H = 0$? Or you just drop $\dot H$?

Comment: $\dot{H}$ with its expression $[L \times [\dot{H} \times L]]$ in a book just stands separetly

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the equality you have written is correct. Let us use the identity

$a \times (b \times c) = b (a,c) - c(a,b)$

we get that $ H \times (\dot{M} \times M) = \dot{M} (H,M) - M (H, \dot{M})$

Substituting your answer we get:

$$\dot{M} (H,M) - M (H, \dot{M}) - H(\dot{M},M)+ M (\dot{M},H)-H(M,\dot{M})+\dot{M}(M,H)$$

On account of the symmetry of the inner product $(X,Y) = (Y,X)$ the only terms that survive cancellation are

$$
2\dot{M} (H,M) - 2 H (\dot{M},M)
$$
which is your expected answer.

Comment: one more question, first and last goes into $2\dot{M}(H,M)$, but the third, and 1 before last does not cancel, only the second and fourth cancel. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry you are right

Comment: yes, but how third and fifth cancel? both of them have the same sign before!

Comment: This is a sign I am also tired, but I checked, indeed these 3rd and 5th add up. I will edit my answer.

Comment: time to go to sleep for me, I hope it helps.

Comment: Nerevtheless thank you! =)